# Can I have two UK accompanying-minor visas simultaneously?

Tags: visas, uk, minors

I am a minor and have a UK accompanying visa with my parents. My parents could not make the trip, so I am going with my sister and applied for a short-term 6 month visa with my sister as my accompanying person. Now I have two visas, one with my parents valid for two years, and one with my sister, valid for 6 months. Both are in the passport. Should I cancel the one with my parents?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have multiple "accompanied" visas, as they are invalid without the named accompanying person anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While the UK generally does not issue concurrent visas, your accompanied-minor visas are specific to those adults with whom you are allowed to enter Britain. You can have both, and there is no need to cancel your earlier visa, nor would you want to; it remains valid (until the expiry date) and lets you visit the UK with your parents.